# How do I get values from url and append them to existing values in url (php)

Tags: php, url, post, url-rewriting, append

I have a link in my page that look like this: `a href=?command=value` but when I click the link and the page reloads it first load another include php file. That redirect the user based on the cookie. like this: `header('Location: ?lang='.$redirect);` So when the page loads the ?command=value is gone.

I need to append `&command=value` in the redirecting include file so the url look like this: `?lang=en_US&command=value`

Comment: So why couldn't you just do `header('Location: ?lang='.$redirect.'&command=value');`?

Comment: The Location header must contain a **full URL**, including 'http://' and the domain name! It might work without, because browsers are tolerant, but it's not supposed to and you shouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like the http_build_query function the most:

```
$variables = $_GET;
$variables['lang'] = $redirect;
header('Location: ' . http_build_query($variables));
```

Like this you keep the existing variables, add your own and use the new query string for the redirect.

Comment: +1 Nicely written. Especially like how it overwrites the lang variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change the redirect line to this:

```
header('Location: ?lang='.$redirect.'&command='.$_GET['command']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like:

`header('Location: ?lang=' . $redirect . '&' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);`

The above will keep any get data that is associated in tack. codersarepeople will only do the command.

Good luck!

EDIT:

One potential down side to this would be if the lang is already in the QUERY_STRING, it will also be appended, so be cautious of that, depending on the uses.